# Write a BASH shell script (program) named "zodiac"

Tags: bash, shell, unix

which accepts as input a person's birthday on the command line and prints Their Western zodiac sign (cancer, leo, libra, etc.) Their Chinese zodiac sign

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service (or exam answering service). You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs, actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve this problem (buy using the `{}`  tool at the top left of the edit box), and people may be able to help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest the basics of writing shell scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash          
echo Hello World
```

Then I would suggest that you research and gather your data about the different domains (zodiac signs, dates, etc).

The following link will get you started with zodiac signs and dates: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/43/aa/50/43aa50c918f3bd03abb71b6d4aaf93c7.jpg

Then simply break your program down into different tasks.

Then the fun starts. You program the different parts of the program.
And remember to check for errors first.

Hope this helps.